# How does dplyr’s between work?

Tags: r, dplyr

I’ve read the documentation and I’ve tried googling it; it should be a simple thing, but it would seem it’s not to me; so I boldly go forth and ask if someone here could explain me how dplyr’s `between()` works.

```
# Explanation documentation
between(x, left, right)

x            A numeric vector of values
left, right: Boundary values
```

I understand a vector is a one-dimensional array, so I suppose `c(1:7)` is a vector, right? I tried using the example provided in the documentation as a template to search for flights july–september, but the following just returns an error:

```
# Example from documentation cont’d
x <- rnorm(1e2)
x[between(x, -1, 1)]

# Loading the library
library(nycflights13)

# Execute my hopeless attempt at between()
flights[between(month, 7, 9)]

# Output and error message
> flights[between(month, 7, 9)]
Error in between(month, 7, 9) : object 'month' not found
```

I feel really daft asking this, but any help in understanding this will be greatly appreciated. I would also apologise for not asking a well-defined question; as is probably appreciated, I really don’t know how to phrase it other than ‘I don’t get it’.

Comment: it's not a question on between but rather on defining your variable: your are filtering your dataframe `flights` by saying "take row where variable month stays between 7 and 9". But `month`is not defined, and R tells it to you. You are rather looking for `flights[between(flights$month, 7, 9)]`.

Comment: If you want to make R understand that `month` refers to the column name in the scope of `flights`, you can do: `with(flights, flights[between(month, 7, 9)])`

Comment: R folks have developed several concepts like with _base_, _tidyverse_, and _data.table_. Subsetting and other things work a bit differenly, which is often confusing. `dplyr` and its `between()` is part of the [tidyverse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyverse/index.html). The way to use it best is probably `flights %>% filter(between(month, 7, 9))` or `filter(flights, between(month, 7, 9))`. You tried base-R subsetting. This also works (you can mix things up), but needs the adjustments mentioned above.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`between` is nothing special — any other function in R would have led to the same problem. Your confusion stems from the fact that dplyr has a lot of functions that allow you to work on data.frame column names as if they were normal variables; for instance:

```
filter(flights, month > 9)
```

However, **`between` is not one of these functions**. As mentioned, it’s simply a normal function. So if you want to use it, you need to provide arguments in the conventional way; for instance:

```
between(flights$month, 7, 9)
```

This will return a logical vector, and you can now use it to index your data.frame:

```
flights[between(flights$month, 7, 9), ]
```

Or, more dplyr-like:

```
flights %>% filter(between(month, 7, 9))
```

Note that *here* we now use non-standard evaluation. But the evaluation is performed by `filter`, not by `between`. `between` is called (by `filter`) using standard evaluation.

Comment: I believe this answer answered all my questions, and well too. Thank you for showing how to address a specific column in a dataset, and for answering so politely and to the point. I’m curious though, as to how I should understand the output of the second line of code you provided (between(flights$month, 7, 9); it yielded a ginormous list of booleans (all of them `FALSE`)

Comment: @CannedMan The output of `between` is the answer to the question “are the values in X between my bounds?” So if I ask `between(c(5, 3, 4, 6, 2, 9, 3), 3, 7)` I’d get the answer TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE. If all your values are `FALSE` this means that none of the months in the `flights` dataset is between 7 and 9.

Comment: and how do you make it non-inclusive the boundaries? i.e. `x > left & x < right`

Comment: @ÖmerAn There’s no specific function so just use the code you’ve written in your comment. Of course you can *wrap* that into your own function.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you want it like this:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(dplyr)

flights %>% filter(between(month,7,9))
```

I see in the meantime this solution also appeared in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

`filter(flights, between(month, 7,9))` seems to work just fine